# Can I use Siri on my iPhone without having to speak?

Tags: iphone, siri, ios

I have Hey Siri enabled and really love it! But sometimes when I want to use Siri I don’t want to speak out loud. Is there a way for me to manually use Siri with a keyboard instead of having to speak? I do not want to turn Hey Siri off. I just want the extra option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want with the **Type to Siri** option.

On your iPhone do as follows:

1. Open Settings
2. Tap on General > Accessibility
3. Swipe up until you see the Siri label
4. Tap on Siri and enable the **Type to Siri** option at top of screen
5. Exit Settings

Now when you hold your Home button down you’ll get a keyboard pop up from the bottom allowing you to type directly to Siri (see screenshot below):

[image]